# If request body is exist it should give me 409

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

*Anyone help please I try to avoid the request if the name exists with NodeJS express *

here is my code

```
/* Post new person to persons */
app.post("/api/persons/", (req, res) => {
  const schema = {
    name: Joi.string().alphanum().min(3).max(30).required(),
    number: Joi.string().min(9).max(30).required(),
  };
  const { error } = validateFunction(req.body);
  const { body } = req;
  const reqValue = persons.some(
    (person) => person.name.toLowerCase() === body.name.toLowerCase()
  );
  if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
  else if (reqValue)
    return res.status(409).send(`${body.name} is already exist`);
  else {
    const person = {
      id: persons.length + 1,
      name: req.body.name,
      number: req.body.number,
    };
```

Comment: You need to describe what your issue is

Comment: https://httpstatuses.com/409 describes what the error means

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue:

```
/* Post new person to persons */
app.post("/api/persons/", (req, res) => {
    const schema = {
        name: Joi.string().exist().alphanum().min(3).max(30).required(),
        number: Joi.string().min(9).max(30).required(),
    };
    const { body } = req;
    const { error } = validateFunction(body, schema);
    const result = persons.filter(({ name }) => name === body.name);

    console.log("resulit", result);
    console.log("The name of request", body.name);

    if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
    else if (result && result.length > 0) return res.status(409).send(`${body.name} is already exist`);
    else {
        const person = {
            id: persons.length + 1,
            name: req.body.name,
            number: req.body.number,
        };
        persons.concat(person);
        res.send(person);
    }
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helped you.